# I am utilizing customtkinter to create a toplevel, but when I try to run it as toplevel and not with main.loop(), it crashes with error

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am working on a GUI program utilizing tkinter and customtkinter. I seem to be getting an annoying error while trying to create this popUpBox. Essential I use it during a script run to open up a pop up box with radio buttons to make a selection. It works fine if I mainloop it, but if i try to run it in the main GUI with mainloop, it crashes, and if I try to run it as topLevel, I get the error at the bottom.

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter


class equipPopUp(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self,titleName,staff,labelFound=''):
        super().__init__()        
        self.rfrBTNList=[]
        self.printBTNList=[]
        
        
        self.labelFound = labelFound
        self.staff = staff
        
        if self.staff == 0:
            self.status = 'Student'
        elif self.staff == 1:
            self.status = 'Staff'
        
        self.titleName = titleName
        
        #### Main Window ###
        self.title(f"{titleName}")
        window_width = 750
        window_height = 600
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
                # find the center point
        center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
        center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)
        self.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')

       
        self.btn1 = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.btn2 = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.btn3 = tkinter.StringVar()
        
        self.label_radio_group = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self,
                                                        text="Please Select Request Equipment:")
        self.label_radio_group.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nw')


        if self.labelFound == 'N':
            z = 0
            Equipment_Requested = ["Print Return Label at SCA", "Email Electronic Return Label", "Email Electronic Return Label"]
            for i in Equipment_Requested:
                z+=1
                self.radio_button = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self,
                                                                text= i,
                                                                variable=self.btn3,
                                                                value=z)
                self.radio_button.grid(row=z,column=0,sticky='nw')


            x = 0
            Equipment_Requested = [f"Replacement {self.status} Kit", f"Replacement {self.status} Printer", "Charger"]
            for i in Equipment_Requested:
                x+=1
                self.radio_button = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self,
                                                                text= i,
                                                                variable=self.btn1,
                                                                value=x,
                                                                command=self.submitButton)
                self.radio_button.grid(row=x,column=1,sticky='nw')
        else:
            x = 0
            Equipment_Requested = [f"Replacement {self.status} Kit", f"Replacement {self.status} Printer", "Charger"]
            for i in Equipment_Requested:
                x+=1
                self.radio_button = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self,
                                                                text= i,
                                                                variable=self.btn1,
                                                                value=x,
                                                                command=self.submitButton)
                self.radio_button.grid(row=x,column=0,sticky='nw')

    
    def createLabelBtns(self):
        y=0
        ra=self.label_radio_group2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self,
                                                        text="Please Select Reason for Return:")
        self.label_radio_group2.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='nw')
        self.rfrBTNList.append(ra)
        rlm = ["Print Return Label at SCA", "Email Electronic Return Label", "Email Electronic Return Label"]
        for i in rlm:
            y+=1
            rb=self.radio_button = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self,
                                                            text= i,
                                                            variable=self.btn3,
                                                            value=y)
            self.radio_button.grid(row=y,column=2,sticky='nw')
            self.rfrBTNList.append(rb) 
    
    
    def createRFRBtns(self):
        y=0
        ra=self.label_radio_group2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self,
                                                        text="Please Select Reason for Return:")
        self.label_radio_group2.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='nw')
        self.rfrBTNList.append(ra)
        equipment_reason_for_return = ["Display", "OS/MB", "Keyboard", "Camera", "Audio/Mic", "Battery", "Physical Damage"]
        for i in equipment_reason_for_return:
            y+=1
            rb=self.radio_button = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self,
                                                            text= i,
                                                            variable=self.btn2,
                                                            value=y)
            self.radio_button.grid(row=y,column=2,sticky='nw')
            self.rfrBTNList.append(rb)
            
        self.my_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, text="Submit", command = self.destroy)
        self.my_button.grid(row=8,column=2,sticky='nw')
            
    def createPrinterChoices(self): 
        y=0
        ra=self.label_radio_group3 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self,
                                                        text="Please Select Reason for Return of Printer:")
        self.label_radio_group3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='nw')
        self.printBTNList.append(ra)
        equipment_reason_for_return = ["Hardware", "Software"]
        for i in equipment_reason_for_return:
            y+=1
            rb=self.radio_button = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self,
                                                            text= i,
                                                            variable=self.btn2,
                                                            value=y)
            self.radio_button.grid(row=y,column=2,sticky='nw')
            self.printBTNList.append(rb)
            
        self.my_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, text="Submit", command = self.destroy)
        self.my_button.grid(row=8,column=2,sticky='nw')
        
   
    def submitButton(self):
        if self.btn1.get()=='1':
            for widget in self.printBTNList:
                widget.grid_remove()
            self.createRFRBtns()
        if self.btn1.get()=='2':
            for widget in self.rfrBTNList:
                widget.grid_remove()
            self.createPrinterChoices()
        if self.btn1.get()=='3':
            for widget in self.rfrBTNList:
                widget.grid_remove()
            for widget in self.printBTNList:
                widget.grid_remove()
            self.my_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, text="Submit", command = self.returnStuff)
            self.my_button.grid(row=8,column=2,sticky='nw')           
            
    
    def submitButton2(self):
        self.destroy

    
    def printSubmitBTN(self):
        # print("Printer"+self.btn2.get())
        pass
    
    
    def returnStuff(self):
        return self.btn1.get(),self.btn2.get(),self.btn3.get()
    
    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()
        print(type(self.btn1.get()))
        print(type(self.btn2.get()))
        print(type(self.btn3.get()))
        return self.btn1.get(),self.btn2.get(),self.btn3.get()
```

The error I am receiving is

```
rlm,ERI,RFRI = equipPopUp('Equipment Requested',staff,'N')
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1652, in cget
return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I am using

```
staff=1
rlm,ERI,RFRI = equipPopUp('Equipment Requested',staff,'N')
```

I can't figure out what is causing it. I have looked into that particular error, and from what I gather, somewhere I am supposedly trying to mix a str and int but I simply can't figure out where it think's I am doing that.
I am using python version 3.9.13

Comment: You should start removing lines of code unit the problem goes away. There's a whole lot of code there that seems unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
rlm,ERI,RFRI = equipPopUp('Equipment Requested',staff,'N')
```

I don't know why you think `equipPopUp(...)` is returning a tuple. Since it's a class, it's returning a single object. Trying to convert the result to a tuple is causing the error.

You can get the exact same error on the second line of this code:

```
popup = equipPopUp('Equipment Requested',staff,'N')
rlm,ERI,RFRI = popup
```

So, to make the error go away, don't try to convert the instance of `equipPopUp` to a tuple.

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense. What would be the recommended way to return with a class? Would setting up 3 functions that give me returns of one of each and then call those work?

Comment: @Nyteghost: research the `wait_window` method. Use that instead of calling `mainloop` in  your `start` method.